# Why is my root view bounds not reflective of the current orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autorotate

In what situation can a root view controller's view bounds not reflective of the current orientation? In supportedInterfaceOrientation of my root view controller, I return landscape, but when I query the frame of my view controller's view, it's showing 320x568 instead.  (The xib is set up to have it be 568x320)

Comment: When are you checking the frame of the view? In what method?

Comment: In viewWillAppear and viewWillLayoutSubviews.